# Search Bar in Laravel with POST

Tags: php, laravel, post, get, searchbar

I added a search bar in my Laravel application. Everything is working fine except for the fact that I am using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

I am stuck on this part and don't know how to change the way it works.

That's my view:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="{{ route('search_bar_route') }}" method="GET">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-controll"
              name="query"
              placeholder="Serach Competitions"
            />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-1 mb-1">
              Search
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="16"
                height="16"
                fill="currentColor"
                class="bi bi-search"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              >
                <path
                  d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"
                />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Function in the Controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $competitions = Competition::orderby('id', 'DESC')->paginate(40);

    if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
        $search_bar_input = $_GET['query'];
        $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_bar_input . '%')
            ->paginate(1)
            ->withQueryString()
        ;
    } else {
        return view('competition.index', compact('competitions'));
    }

    return view('competition.index', compact('competitions'));
}
```

My route:

```php
Route::get("/search", [CompetitionController::class, 'index'])->name('search_bar_route');
```

Comment: first of all, in laravel u can use `$request->get('query')` / `request()->get('query')` instead of `$_GET['query']`. also, the else statement is useless, since after the if-else block u r doing the same thing that u do in the else.

and u should explain better what u mean with "don't know how to change the way it works." - what u wanna do exactly, what is the issue?

Comment: What is your expected output? @Yorkata

Comment: @ericmp Thanks for suggesting `->get()`. My problem is for security reasons I dont want to send a GET request with data typed by users in a form. A post request would be more appropriated.But I dont know how to make it work with `POST`

Comment: @Sajidanwar ideally the same. As I said its working fine but want to change the method to `POST`

Comment: a search feature is normally a get request, not a post request. imagine google search making the requests via post. how would u store/share a search to someone? the url wouldnt contain the stuff that u r searching and is not sensible data, can and should be shown

Comment: and `->get()`, in laravel, behind the scenes, does the same as `$_GET`. why dont u want to use the laravel helpers? why u use laravel if u want to keep using plain php?

Comment: the method for getting input from the request is `input` ... `get` is only there because it comes from Symfony, Laravel added `input` as it has a different priority to the input bags it uses first ... from the docblock for `get`: `This method belongs to Symfony HttpFoundation and is not usually needed when using Laravel.`

Answer (score 0):

you need to figure how to use request in laravel we don't use `$_GET` or global var from **PHP**
if you send data by **GET** method you may need to use `$request()->get(your name data )` as @ericmp mention comment in your problem
you can check laravel doc for farther info about http requests you may need in the following link : [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests)

if you got an issue in a filter result you can edit the competitions to be like that

```
        $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where('name', '%' . $search_bar_input . '%')
            ->paginate(1)
            ->withQueryString();
```

the best practice is

```
        $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where('name', '%' . reuqest()->get('query'). '%')
            ->paginate(1)
            ->withQueryString();
```

and you can check the reuqest data if you faced any issue by `dd(request()->get('query'));`
put it into index function and before your conditions